# How can I add same uiview multiples times at different positions to a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to achieve this in swift. [image]

So far I created my own custom view which is a subclass of UIView class:

```
 class MyConnections: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
    let circle = CGRectMake(5, 60, 80, 80)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, circle)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, circle)

}

}
```

This is my view controller where I add the above view as a subview:

```
let profile = MyConnections()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profile.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    view.addSubview(profile)
    self.profile.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    //constraints for the location button
    let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.profile, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 10)
    let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.profile
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 20)
    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.profile, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 150)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.profile, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 150)

    self.view.addConstraints([verticalConstraint, horizontalConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint])
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

All the code above gives me a circle on top. Now I want to repeat that same circle multiple times at different positions as seen in the image. I can create multiple instances of the uiview add them as subview but every time I will have to define new constraints for it which I don't want to do.

Can anyone please help me and give me an efficient answer?

Comment: `UICollectionView` may be better for such a thing.

Comment: How about a `UICollectionView`?

Comment: @rmaddy  I want to create a collection view without using storyboards. My entire project uses .xib files. I was not able to find any tutorial which showed creating collection views without storyboards. Can you share some links here?

Answer (score 6):

You should know a UIView can have a single superview/parent. If you add it as a subview at a different position (using addSubview method) it will be removed from the first position and added as a subview to the new position.
In your case to add more subviews you have to create more UIView objects not use a single global UIView.
If the layout is repetitive a UITableView / UICollectionView is a better choice.

Comment: thanks guys for the answers, but I want to create a collection view without using storyboards. My entire project uses .xib files. I was not able to find any tutorial which showed creating collection views without storyboards. Can you share some links here?

Comment: It is pretty late I guess, but for other people who have not come across this yet, you can make a collection view or pretty much any other view programmatically. For a collection view, you just declare the view programmatically just like what you have up there for a uiview , just keep in mind you need to declare the layout programmatically as well in case you are using flow layout.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement and UI qualify for a UICollectionView I think you should use `UICollectionView` and can create a custom `UICollectionViewCell` with round image and and badge view as well, and they add dataSource and delegate methods. That will not only help in creating UI but it will make your app more performant by reusing cells
[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) is a nice tutorial about `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified view to create collection view programmatically: 
make the collection view and layout programmatically just like any other view you would code and add it as subview like below:

```
lazy var myCollectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = YourFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = self.direction;
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    cv.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    return cv
}()
```

and your flow layout could be something like:

```
mport UIKit

class Yourflowlayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

    return super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)?.map {
        attrs in
        let attrscp = attrs.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        self.applyLayoutAttributes(attributes: attrscp)
        return attrscp
    }

}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
    if let attrs = super.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {
        let attrscp = attrs.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        self.applyLayoutAttributes(attributes: attrscp)
        return attrscp
    }
    return nil
}


func applyLayoutAttributes(attributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    if attributes.representedElementKind != nil {
        return
    }

    if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
        let stride = (self.scrollDirection == .horizontal) ? collectionView.frame.size.width : collectionView.frame.size.height
        let offset = CGFloat(attributes.indexPath.section) * stride
        var xCellOffset : CGFloat = CGFloat(attributes.indexPath.item) * self.itemSize.width
        var yCellOffset : CGFloat = CGFloat(attributes.indexPath.item) * self.itemSize.height
        if(self.scrollDirection == .horizontal) {
            xCellOffset += offset;
        } else {
            yCellOffset += offset
        }
        attributes.frame = CGRect(x: xCellOffset, y: yCellOffset, width: self.itemSize.width, height: self.itemSize.height)
    }
}
```

}

You can add the collectionView in your other classes  as a subview , make sure you have the 
`myCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` so that your constrains are applied and you actually see the collection view and of course add your constrains or give it a frame.

Hope that helps someone.